# Making HTTP requests Illegal Path in Golang

Tags: rest, api, http, go, networking

I have a question, for security purposes, it is sometimes very useful to make HTTP requests with illegal paths, such as: `http://localhost/%x`, in Golang it does not seem to be a way to do that, could anyone give some light to this issue?
What I have tried so far:
- .Get() function

```golang
response, err := http.DefaultClient.Get("http://localhost/%x")
if err != nil{
    panic(err) // net/url.EscapeError
}
```

- .Do() function

```golang
    requestObject, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://localhost/%x", nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err) // panics!
    }
```

And

```golang
    requestObject, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://localhost", nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err) // Not panic
    }
    requestObject.URL.Path = "/%x"
    response, err = netClient.goHttpClient.Do(requestObject)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err) // Not panic
    }
```

This last one looks promising, but request is made to `%25x` instead of `%x`, can someone give some help please?

**UPDATE**:
Go can send %x in the request, in the query section though, not in the path, I want to send %x in the path, so my issue is not solved:

```golang
requestObject, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://localhost", nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err) // Not panic
    }
requestObject.URL.Path = "/%x"
requestObject.URL.RawQuery = "%x"
```

Request is made to `http://localhost/%25x?%x` The %x in the path is encoded, in the query it is not.

**UPDATE:**

The answer given @Cerise is the one I use, and it works fine, but there are edge cases to take into account. 
1 - Proxy: If you have to forward the requests to a proxy, for some reason, the HTTP framework does not know how to send HTTP requests that your proxy can understand, to fix this, in Burp suite, you have to enable invisible proxy as documented here: https://portswigger.net/support/using-burp-suites-invisible-proxy-settings-to-test-a-non-proxy-aware-thick-client-application
This still has an issue, I noticed it when I had to debug some HTTP requests, I could not make sense, of what Burp Suite was telling me, then inspecting the requests in Wireshark I knew there was something wrong, if you use .Opaque + BurpSuite, BurpSuite will modify some requests, this is where the second issue comes into play, keep reading.
2 - Opaque does not handle well the paths starting with "//", I don't think it is a bug though, it is well known that https://stackoverflow.com can also be rewritten as //stackoverflow.com, I think this the logic taken into account by go, anyway, if you do:

```golang
requestObject, err := http.NewRequest(methodStr, "http://localhost", nil)
requestObject.URL.Opaque = "//something"
```

This is what the HTTP request looks like with Wireshark:

```
GET http://something HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ca;q=0.8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Pragma: no-cache
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

notice the first line, it is not what we may have though first, right?

I used to debug HTTP requests with Burp Suite, but let's use the same code, and forward the requests to Burp using:

```golang
http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).Proxy = http.ProxyURL("http://localhost:8080")
```

Don't forget to enable invisible proxy on BurpSuite, otherwise it will reject the request. What Burp Suite shows is:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ca;q=0.8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Pragma: no-cache
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

outch!!, Burp has changed our request completely!!!
Takeaways:
- Do not use Your HTTP proxy to debug requests made with Opaque
- Do not use .Opaque with paths starting with double slashes, use the following:

```golang
       if strings.HasPrefix(yourPath, "//") {
            requestObject.URL.Path = fmt.Sprintf("%s", yourPath)
        } else {
            requestObject.URL.Opaque = fmt.Sprintf("%s", yourPath)
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set Request.URL.Opaque to the invalid path.  The [Opaque](https://godoc.org/net/url#URL.Opaque) data is written to the network as is.

```
requestObject, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://localhost", nil)
if err != nil {
    panic(err) 
}
requestObject.URL.Opaque = "/%x"
response, err = netClient.goHttpClient.Do(requestObject)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

This code creates an invalid request. The net/http server handles the invalid request by responding with 400 Bad Request. Other servers and proxies may do something different.

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/KfY6Bxwi7Bp)

Comment: I would just like to add something, for other readers, .Opaque works and does what I asked for, but if someone has the additional requirement of tunneling the illegal request through a local proxy, then for some reason, if Opaque is used, Golang no longer sends a request a Proxy could understand, Burp Suite will not be able to handle it, unless you enable "invisible proxying": https://portswigger.net/support/using-burp-suites-invisible-proxy-settings-to-test-a-non-proxy-aware-thick-client-application

Comment: I have something to add, which is very important, I noticed something(perhaps a bug?) if we set Opaque to a string having starting with //, for example //index, the request is made   asking for https://index, at HTTP level this looks like this: "GET https://index HTTP/1.1", to get around this I have an if condition, then use Opaque or .Path depending on each scenario, I detailed this in the question above